# Check the soft keyboard hidden or shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have code in which I want to detect the soft keyboard shown or hidden.

I saw here [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265) an answer from Reuben Scratton, but I have troble with the following points:

1. I can not implement it in my MainActivity.
2. The XML file gives the ERROR:

   ```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext
   cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   ```

How can i solve these problems?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Thanks your kind concern. It was my mistake, I am not extending it Activity.